# View more than 20 most recent documents in MongoDB Compass from Schema

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I want to be able to edit some documents in my Mongo DB from compass, but a query only shows 20 of the most recent results.  How can I view more than that 20?  Or at least view the next 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/query-bar/) ...

> You can specify a query filter in the query bar. If you click Options to expand the query bar, you also have access to the project, sort, skip, and limit options of the query.

[image]

So, if you click on `Options` you can:

- Get more than 20 docs by changing the value of `Limit` from the default (`20`) to a value of your choosing
- Get the next *N* documents by changing the value of `Skip`

Comment: Thank you, i did play around with the Limit figure and noticed that the number next to the (i) changed, but failed to see the arrows that appear that allow you to skip through the pages.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Changing the limit changes the TOTAL value, not the page size value! I start with 1-20 of 141 and when changing the limit to 50 I then get 1-20 of 50 - that's not the ask