# Can mongo aggregation match return all documents using MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 24 documents with the same user ID, when I want to match it all, mongo aggregation returns me only 20 elements but must return all 24. Is it limited by mongo or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you trying on mongo prompt? if yes, then it will by default show 20 records. To see more, you can type `it` which will show you next 20..

Comment: Please mention the tool you're using to run the aggregation query

Answer (score 2):

Step 1. Click on the setting icon on the top right corner :

[image: Step 1]

Step 2. Change the "Number of Preview Documents" as per requirement :

[image: Step 2]

Answer (score 1):

### [Cursor Behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

Mongo shell automatically iterates the cursor up to 20 times, as mentioned documentation.

But you can use the `DBQuery.shellBatchSize` to change the number of iteration from the default value 20. 
[See Working with the mongo Shell for more information.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#mongo-shell-executing-queries)

P.s. Yes, Compass has limited number of documents for aggregation by design.

---

[MongoDB Compass 1.14.0:](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/aggregation-pipeline-builder/#aggregation-pipeline-builder)

> the Preview of Documents in the Collection section of the Aggregations
>   view displays 20 documents sampled from the current collection.

---

Additional links:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#format-printed-results
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#specify-an-initial-batch-size
https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/aggregation-pipeline-builder/#aggregation-pipeline-builder
[How to print out more than 20 items (documents) in MongoDB's shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705517/how-to-print-out-more-than-20-items-documents-in-mongodbs-shell)

Comment: I set it in .mongorc.js, but it works only on mongoShell, it doesn't work in MongoCompass and in my aggregation.

Comment: @ТарасДанальченко did you try [to specify a query filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48445906/8370915) using MongoDB Compass?

Comment: mmmm,I said about aggregation, not about the filter

Comment: @ТарасДанальченко Sorry, I'll check it. But as I see from the section [Aggregation Pipeline Builder](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/aggregation-pipeline-builder/#aggregation-pipeline-builder) in Compass version 1.14.0, you can display just 20 by design.