# MongoDB Compass displaying documents 20 limit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I want to able Compass show more than 20 documents per 'page' 
e.g. 1-100 of 400

Screen of problem:

[image]

Already tried: 
[View more than 20 most recent documents in MongoDB Compass from Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48445387/view-more-than-20-most-recent-documents-in-mongodb-compass-from-schema)
I don't need to limit all results

[How to print out more than 20 items (documents) in MongoDB's shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705517/how-to-print-out-more-than-20-items-documents-in-mongodbs-shell)
On this step i want see results in Compass itself. DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 300 do nothing - tried in shell and restart mongo+compass both

Comment: I would suspect it's hard coded. Despite *"gradual improvement"* you really should not be viewing Compass as anything more than a basic "data explorer" with some other "dashboard metrics". In fact if you "post screenshots" of your documents in questions here, then expect to be scolded for it. We would prefer you instead use the `mongo` shell for representing data in your Stack Overflow questions since it's "text" form can be easily copied and pasted. Personally I don't ever use such GUI products, and either copy/paste from an external editor into a `mongo` shell, or use an external language.

Comment: Note that AFAIK you can create "plugins" for Compass, but again to my knowledge the available API for such plugins does not expose that part of the UI.

Comment: nice advise, thanks!

Comment: An issue has been logged in the Compass JIRA project: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-3895

Comment: That issue is closed and its resolution is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can export data to json or csv without paging limit by using menu Collection->Export Collection and then 'Export Full Collection'

http://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/import-export/